# Newly installed Ubuntu boots at GNU GRUB terminal (version 2.02)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I’m new to Ubuntu, or Linux in this case, and what I did was install Ubuntu on my PC. I really don’t know anything about this operating system since I was a Windows user for the most of my life. I have seen some people who also had this problem but, as a newbie, I still don’t understand.

I have 2 hard drives, one WD blue and one Seagate Barracuda, both 1TB. I partitioned half of the Barracuda for use in Windows and the other half is for the installation of Ubuntu. I used a boot drive to install Ubuntu. I just followed the usual instructions on the Ubuntu website but still I’m faced with a dead end. Though I believe it is supposed to be booting at the GNU GRUB menu not terminal.

I have seen some posts about `set pager=1` and `ls`, but in this case I think mine is like this: 
so,

```
grub> set pager=1
grub> ls 
(hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) (hd2) (hd2,gpt5) (hd2,gpt4) (hd2,gpt3) (hd2,gpt2) (hd2,gpt1)
```

And when the `ls (hd0,1)` part came, it said

```
error: disk ‘hd0,1’ not found.
```

Any help about this? If the answer was very obvious, I’m really sorry for my stupidity.

If the specs of my PC is needed, well here it is:

Intel i5 3350P
An acer motherboard from an aspire m3985
10 GB of ddr3 ram
Nvidia GeForce GTX 750ti 2GB
1TB WD blue
1TB Seagate Barracuda

Sorry for asking a stupid question. I only know much about Windows. I already spent 5 hours+ trying to just boot on Ubuntu lol.

Comment: Then you may find this link useful... https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

Comment: Can you boot up into your live Ubuntu USB (Try Ubuntu). Then r. click on the desktop --> Open Terminal. Run command `sudo parted -l` then paste output here (to copy, drag mouse over output and presss Cntrl+Shft+C).